# Apple and stripe : Merchant id/apple pay certificate could not seen in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments, applepay

I have followed every steps to create stripe credit card payment functionality with apple pay in my app.
It is works fine for my xcode and merchant id/bundle id.

**What I need:** 
My client have his own apple developer account, and he want to add his client's merchant id in app.

**What I have from client:**
1. IOS developer certificate(with Bundle id)
2. Apple pay certificate
3. Merchant id

I have added developer certificate and apple pay certificate in key chain. as well as changed **"Build settings -> code signing" with clients developer certificate**.

**Problem:**
Here "**capability -> Apple pay -> merchant id**" of client id does not displayed.
If I click on "fix issue". xcode redirect me to select my developer profile.

Please confirm is this information is enough. If yes please assist me to solve this.

**My screen is now look like this When I click on add/refresh :**

[image]

Please tell me what I missing

Comment: Still not resolved. I have wested my whole week on this

Answer (score 2):

Have you created these certificates on your machine. If not then ask for p12 certificate. It will resolve your issue.

@AkshayPatil : You are facing this issue only because of wrong certificates or wrong process.

1. Check whether "Apple Pay" is activated or not before certificate was created.
2. You should get .p12 certificate when someone create these certificate on another machine
3. You should use same apple account to activate "Apple Pay" otherwise you will not be able to access these certificates and Apple pay will throw an error.
   I tried on my machine. It works fine. You should add "merchant." before merchant ID.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I did not ask for p12 certificate. I would ask but can you please tell me what is p12 certificate and why we use p12

Comment: I got ios_distribution.cer from client. I searched on other site. I can not find any relationship with p12 and adding merchant id. Can you give me any steps?

Comment: Still not resolved. I have wested my whole week on this.

Comment: @AkshayPatil : You are facing this issue only because of wrong certificates or wrong process. 
1. Check whether "Apple Pay" is activated or not before certificate was created.
2. You should get .p12 certificate when someone create these certificate on another machine
3. You should use same apple account to activate "Apple Pay" otherwise you will not be able to access these certificates and Apple pay will throw an error.

Comment: I have verified that Apple pay certificate and .p12 certificate from same account. My problem is not about apple pay error. I can not see merchant id in  "capability -> Apple pay -> merchant id"

Comment: @AkshayPatil You should integrate Apple ID and password. Ask client  for apple ID and Password and create your own certificates or get .p12 file because you are not authenticated user.
xCode -> Preferences -> Account -> check whether the apple account is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add manually and test it. See screenshot[image]

Comment: That will be ok.. but Can tell me steps/process to add ?

Comment: I have updated the question, because of that I can not add manually merchant id

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem appear when I tried to add Apple Pay to my capabilities. 
Nothing really worked, except for disabling automatic signing, downloading a Development profile from developer.apple.com, importing it, having it error out, and then re-enabling automatic signing.

That made everything work again.