# Apple pay with stripe : can not add merchant id

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, stripe-payments, applepay

I have already ask this question :

[Apple and stripe : Merchant id/apple pay certificate could not seen in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396961/apple-and-stripe-merchant-id-apple-pay-certificate-could-not-seen-in-xcode)

Problem:
I want build/Ipa using clients account details.

What I have from client:
1) IOS developer cer
2) IOS distribution cer
3) Apple pay cer
4) P12 cer

All these certificates are in my keychain now.

What is happing now:
I click on "capability -> Apple pay " xcode redirect me to select my developer profile.

What I want : Xcode should check merchant id from clients account not from my account.

Please tell me what I missing.

Please tell me what I missing.

Comment: You have to create Merchant ID and Apple Pay certificate in your apple account. After you can access your merchant id from Capability->Apple Pay in Xcode. Please refer this https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/apple-pay

Comment: This is what my client did: 
1) Created merchant ID on his account
1) Created CSR(request file) from his stripe account.
2) using this csr created apple pay certificate using merchant id that created erlier
3) Downloaded that cer and uploaded on stripe
4) Now I have same cerificate and merchant ID /n

I think I missing some xcode certificates that need to import developer in xcode Am I right?

Comment: Make sure your account in which merchant ID created and apple account for your application both are same. if yes than you have to set ON "Apple Pay" capability from your Xcode and refresh it to get your merchant ID.

Comment: Yes there is same account for merchant ID created and apple account.
When I try to set Apple pay "ON" in capability xcode pop up's "Select developer account" and there is only one account i.e my account.
Here I want to select my clients account.